# Printing passed bytes from Exception

Tags: python, exception, python-3.3, try-except, poplib

This seems to be the code for the poplib.error_proto.

```
class error_proto(Exception): pass
```

It just passes the bytes from the POP response in the exception.  What I would like to do is catch any exception, take those bytes, use .decode('ascii') on them, and print them as a string.  I've written my own test setup like so:

```
class B(Exception): pass

def bex(): raise B(b'Problem')

try:
    bex()
except B as err:
    print(err.decode('ascii'))
```

I've tried replacing the last line with:

```
    b = bytes(err)
    print(b.decode('ascii'))
```

But to no avail.  Is this possible and if so, how would I implement this?

UPDATE:  Though, as falsetru points out, the documentation says results are returned as strings, this is not the case:

```
>>> p = poplib.POP3('mail.site.com')
>>> p.user('skillian@site.com')
b'+OK '
>>> p.pass_('badpassword')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 201, in pass_
    return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 164, in _shortcmd
    return self._getresp()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\poplib.py", line 140, in _getresp
    raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: b'-ERR authorization failed  Check your server settings.'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`poplib.error_proto` documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/poplib.html#poplib.error_proto):

> Exception raised on any errors from this module (errors from socket module are not caught). The reason for the exception is passed to the constructor as a **string**.

So, you don't need to decode it.

---

**UPDATE** It seems like the documentation does not match the actual implementation.

You can access the arguments passed to the exception constructor using [`args`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException.args) attribute.

```
p = poplib.POP3('mail.site.com')
try:
    p.user('skillian@site.com')
    p.pass_('badpassword')
except poplib.error_proto as e:
    print(e.args[0].decode('ascii')) # `'ascii'` is not necessary.
```

Comment: Please see my update, doesn't the `b` prefix mean it is `bytes()`?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what I was looking for.  And I always saw `decode('utf-8')`, so I figured `'ascii'` was required for ASCII.  That's a two-fer!

Comment: @Sean, utf-8 encoding is designed to be backward compatible with ascii encoding. And `encoding` parameter of [`bytes.decode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#bytes.decode) defaults to `utf-8`; You can omit it. :)